# Is there any way to make the child element of a parent div have a fixed width?

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<style>
        .service-info p {
  padding: 100px 0;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: red;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.service-info {
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  width: min(95%, 70rem);
}
</style>
<body>
  <div class="service-info">
    <h1>services</h1>
    <p>lorem ipsum randomaora ni salisum pumm.lorem ipsum randomaora ni salisum pumm.lorem ipsum randomaora ni salisum pumm.lorem ipsum randomaora ni salisum pumm.lorem ipsum randomaora ni salisum pumm.lorem ipsum randomaora ni salisum pumm.</p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is there any way to make the child element of a parent div have a fixed width without it increasing or reducing in size when you resize the webpage using the inspect tool, But the defined width is applied irrespective of the screen size.
at 320px screen size i want the div to have a fix width even when increasing the width size.

Comment: What do you mean by fixed width? A set pixel value, a set percentage or what?

Comment: I think what you're searching for is [max-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width). E.g. you could set a div to have a width of 100% but a max-width of 600px. This would make the div take up all the space on smaller screen sizes but limit itself to 600px even when more space is available.

Comment: i meant pixel, cause its fixed, while percentage is not